# Memory error when running k_cliques_community

Tags: python, anaconda, networkx

I run `k_cliques_community` on my network data and  received a memory error after a long respond time. The code works perfectly fine for my other data but not this one.

```
c = list(k_clique_communities(G_fb, 3))
list(c[0])
```

Here is a snap shot of the trace error
[image]

Comment: I realize this is old, but if you multithread the task, it would take a lot longer for you to run into a memory error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running your code on my system with 16 GB RAM and i7 -7700HQ, the kernel died after returning a memory error. I think it's because the computation of k-cliques of size 3 is taking a lot of computational power/memory since you have quite a large no. of nodes and edges. I think you need to look into other ways to find k-cliques, like [GraphX - Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/graphx-programming-guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an x32 installation of python. x32 installations are limited to 2 gigabytes of memory regardless of how much system memory you have. This is inconvenient, but it works. Uninstall python and install an x64 installation. Again, it's inconvenient, but it's the only solution that I've ever seen.

Comment: I am using Anaconda

Comment: @JamesXiang I am by no means an Anaconda expert, but when you download, you can still download an x64 or x32, if my memory serves me correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the **networkx** documentation:

*To obtain a list of all maximal cliques, use list(find_cliques(G)). However, be aware that in the worst-case, the length of this list can be exponential in the number of nodes in the graph.*

(this is referred to `find_cliques`, but it is related to your problem also).

That means, if there is a huge number of cliques, the strings you create with `list` will be so many that you'll probably run out of memory: strings need more space than int values to be saved.
I don't know if there is a work-around tho.